# sony-smarteyeglass: How to add description above menu of notification view

Tags: android, sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I am trying to modify HelloNotification sample code given in SonyEyeGlass SDK samples. As described in https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/guides/notifications/
we can add a menu to be shown in the notification view when the user drills down into the notification details(Action menu with 3 Action Toasts as shown in that link and example).

But in SmartEyeglass screen **I want to add some description above this menu, as that area is empty. Is there any API that I can use for showing any text description in that empty area?** (probably using Notification.SourceColumns) ?

Please help.

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to draw above the menu.  If you really need to draw on that area you would have to build a Control extension and use your own menu control on the bottom.